# Internet Explorer remembers webpages after reset

Tags: internet-explorer, history

After I formatted my Lumia 920 as expected whole webpages, photos, musics etc. had been deleted but just one webpage hadn't been deleted. When I opened Internet Explorer, it was remembering this webpage. I wonder where did it remember it from and bring that website? Does my Microsoft account save the links which I search? If yes, where it saves?

I still use my Lumia 920 and sometimes I "delete history" from explorer. When I do this, it deletes every webpage except the one I mentioned above. What can I do? I want to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

With Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8, Microsoft introduced the ability for you to roam the currently opened tabs, and maintain them across reboots. It also allows you to open a tab that you were looking at on another device (so if you find something whilst on the train on your phone, you can then open the same tab on your desktop when you get home).

This is implemented by roaming a small amount of data between your devices and Microsoft's servers, and can therefore survive a hard reset.

Comment: I see you but my trouble is deleting that surviving page.

Comment: You can use the "tabs" button to view the open tabs, and close it with the "x" button (this is also where you can open tabs from other associated Windows 8 devices)

Comment: I am sorry but there is nothing also there. Just an blank page. When I press "x" button for it directs me to Internet Explorer. I think it is default. (Cannot closed)